# Cookies Stripped After Being Set but Before Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, cookies

I'm having a problem where I am able to retrieve two cookies from a login call from one web service but both cookies are stripped from any requests made to a different web service.

A little background: I have a Windows service (.NET 4.5) that needs to send data to another companies web service interface. Their interface is made up of a couple different independent web services. To connect I have to call a log in web method from one of their services; I'll call it service A. The log in method returns a Long value made up of DateTime ticks as well as two cookies: a session cookie and an authorization cookie. Both cookies must be included in every request.

If I call any of the methods in service A both cookies are included in the request. Using Fiddler I have been able to verify this. However, if I attempt to call a method in service B, both cookies get stripped from the request call before it is made.

Here are the classes and code I am currently using:

**CookieBehavior Class**

```
public sealed class CookieBehavior : IContractBehavior, IEndpointBehavior, IClientMessageInspector
    {
        #region Private fields
        public CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        #endregion

        #region Public constructors
        public CookieBehavior()
            : this(true)
        {
        }

        public CookieBehavior(Boolean shared)
        {
            this.Shared = shared;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public properties
        public Boolean Shared
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private methods
        private void getCookies(HttpResponseMessageProperty prop, CookieContainer cookieContainer)
        {
            if (prop != null)
            {
                String header = prop.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

                if (header != null)
                {
                    String[] cookies = header.Split(',');
                    var cc = new CookieCollection();
                    foreach (string cookie in cookies)
                    {
                        if (cookie.Contains(";"))
                        {
                            cc.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Substring(0, cookie.IndexOf("=")),
                                cookie.Substring(cookie.IndexOf("=") + 1, cookie.IndexOf(";") - (cookie.IndexOf("=") + 1))));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cc.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Substring(0, cookie.IndexOf("=")), cookie.Substring(cookie.IndexOf("=") + 1)));
                        }
                    }
                    cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(@"http://tempuri.org"), cc);
                }
            }
        }

        private void setCookies(HttpRequestMessageProperty prop, CookieContainer cookieContainer)
        {
            if (prop != null)
            {
                prop.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri(@"http://tempuri.org")));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region IClientMessageInspector Members

        void IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, Object correlationState)
        {
            if (((this.Shared == true) ? CookieContext.Current.cookieContainer : this.cookieContainer).Count == 0)
            {
                HttpResponseMessageProperty prop = reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name.ToString()] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
                this.getCookies(prop, (this.Shared == true) ? CookieContext.Current.cookieContainer : this.cookieContainer);
            }
        }

        Object IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty prop = null;
            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name.ToString()))
                prop = request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name.ToString()] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
            else
                prop = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            this.setCookies(prop, (this.Shared == true) ? CookieContext.Current.cookieContainer : this.cookieContainer);
            return (null);
        }
        #endregion

        #region IEndpointBehavior Members

        void IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ClientRuntime behavior)
        {
            behavior.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
        }

        void IEndpointBehavior.Validate(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint)
        {
        }

        #endregion

        #region IContractBehavior Members

        void IContractBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        void IContractBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(this);
        }

        void IContractBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
        }

        void IContractBehavior.Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**CookieContext Class**

```
public class CookieContext : IDisposable
    {
        #region Internal fields
        internal CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        #endregion

        #region Private static fields
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static CookieContext current = null;
        #endregion

        #region Public static constructor
        public CookieContext()
        {
            current = this;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public static properties
        public static CookieContext Current
        {
            get
            {
                return (current);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Members

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            this.cookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri(@"http://tempuri.org"), String.Empty);
            this.cookieContainer = null;
            current = null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**My Code**

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

                    using (var cookieCtx = new CookieContext())
                    {
                        ServiceA.ServiceASoapClient serviceA_req = new ServiceA.ServiceASoapClient();
                        ServiceB.ServiceBSoapClient serviceB_req = new ServiceB.ServiceBSoapClient();

                        var cookieBhr = new CookieBehavior(true);

                        serviceA_req.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(cookieBhr);
                        serviceB_req.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(cookieBhr);

                        long? loginTicks = serviceA_req.InterfaceLogin();

                        if (loginTicks.HasValue) 
                        {
                            // Get/Set data for request call

                            serviceB_resp = serviceB_req.SendData(fooBar);
                        }

                    }
```

Debugging my application has shown that both cookie headers are correctly set from the request yet they are stripped prior to the service B request.

Why would the both cookies get stripped from the second request?